# Typescript Error ';' expected. 'EventNameString' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

I'm trying to add firebase phone authentication to an old ionic project, followed several tutorials. I manged to implement it, but every time I do `ionic serve -l` this error appears:

[image: errors screenshot]

However I noticed that the errors disappear if I commented one of those lines in `app.modules.ts` after I do `ionic serve -l` :

```
import { AngularFireModule } from "@angular/fire";
import { AngularFireAuth } from "@angular/fire/auth";
```

since the errors is in the node-modules folder, I tried removing it multiple times and even tried it on other PC, followed some answers here and there but I couldn't solve it.

Errors text:

```
Typescript Error
';' expected.
gtagName?: string;
/** Sets custom name for `dataLayer` array used by gtag. */
dataLayerName?: string;

Typescript Error
'EventNameString' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
/** Sets custom name for `dataLayer` array used by gtag. */
dataLayerName?: string;

Typescript Error
'never' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
/** Sets custom name for `dataLayer` array used by gtag. */
dataLayerName?: string;

Typescript Error
Cannot find name 'T'.
/** Sets custom name for `dataLayer` array used by gtag. */
dataLayerName?: string;
```

ionic info :

```
Ionic Framework: ^3.9.8
Ionic App Scripts: 3.2.4
Angular Core: ^5.2.7
Angular Compiler CLI: ^5.2.7
Node: 12.13.1
OS Platform: Windows 10
Navigator Platform: Win32
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36
```

`app.modules.ts` imported dependencies:

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable, Injector, NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from "ionic-angular";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { HttpModule } from "@angular/http";
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";

import { Geolocation } from "@ionic-native/geolocation";
import { NativeGeocoder } from "@ionic-native/native-geocoder";

import { MyApp } from "./app.component";
import { TabsPage } from "../pages/tabs/tabs";
import { Loading } from "../pages/loading/loading";
import { Welcome } from "../pages/welcome/welcome";
import { GeoPage } from "../pages/geo/geo";

import { IonicStorageModule } from "@ionic/storage";
import { StatusBar } from "@ionic-native/status-bar";
import { SplashScreen } from "@ionic-native/splash-screen";

import { APIService } from "../services/api_service";
import { CartService } from "../services/cart_service";
import { PushService } from "../services/push_service";
import { UtilService } from "../services/util_service";
import { OrderHistoryService } from "../services/order_history_service";

import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule } from "@ngx-translate/core";
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from "@ngx-translate/http-loader";
import { RestaurantsPageModule } from "../pages/catalog/restaurants/restaurants.module";
import { GeoPageModule } from "../pages/geo/geo.module";
import { AngularFireModule } from "@angular/fire";
import { AngularFireAuth } from "@angular/fire/auth";
import { firebaseConfig } from "../config";
import { LoginPage } from "../pages/personal/login/login";
import { AuthService } from "../services/auth.service";
import { NgxErrorsModule } from '@ultimate/ngxerrors';
```

Comment: i would try cleaning node_modules and it's cache and reinstall it fresh..

Comment: @nircraft I did that many times and even tried it on a new setup PC: `git clone`'ed it  then did `npm install`. every thing works fine until I start implementing firebase feature.. this problem is really weird

Answer (score 0):

The main thing is you must have being you are using `=` instead of `:` with `EventNameString` when attempting to set the type to `EventNameString`. Thats why you are getting the error 'EventNameString' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

For other please those are mainly syntax errors as I see. As @nircraft suggested you should try cleaning `node_modules` and it's `cache` and reinstall it fresh.

Comment: But if you looked at this [error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Czi2e.png) the error is pointing to the same line of that file in `node-modules` folder, which I didn't modify it.
also, I did clean the `node-moduels` and it's `cache` multiple times with the same result.